# DrawerLayout: Putting button to the center of The main content view

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a problem putting button to the center of the main content view using DrawerLayout

I have basic .xml layout that can be found in almost every Navigation Drawer example. My question is, how do i set this layout so i would be able to put buttons center aligned, textview on the bottom and so on.. Is that even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the layout utilized in the `fragment_navigation_drawer.xml`, for example the one created in Android Studio Wizard:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccc"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

them you can wrap your view(s) in a `ViewGroup`, e. g.:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc"
    tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navivation_drawer_list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and set `android:layout_gravity="center"` (or `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` if you added a `RelativeLayout`).

**Generally speaking**: If you have a `RelativeLayout` as a parent, you can use attributes like:

```
android:layout_alignLeft
android:layout_alignParentBottom
android:layout_alignParentEnd
android:layout_alignParentLeft
android:layout_alignParentRight
android:layout_alignParentStart
android:layout_alignParentTop
android:layout_alignRight
...
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

And if you have (pretty much) anything else:

```
android:layout_gravity
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html